# helm not working on rancher with kubernetes

Tags: nginx, charts, kubernetes, rancher, kubernetes-helm

We followed the quick start guide for the Rancher with kubernetes environment, and followed all the steps and exercises from [this](http://info.rancher.com/deploying-scaling-kubernetes-ebook) ebook.

Everything was Beautiful, with one exception: helm chart manager is not working.

We found [this](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/7539) issue that had a lot of people talking about nginx configurations that apparently solved it, but it did not for us.

When we run helm like:

```
> helm install --name prom-release stable/prometheus
```

It returns:

```
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 35.227.80.81:10250: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

We appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/kubernetes/addons/#helm

Using helm in the Rancher UI

Rancher provides shell access directly to a managed kubectl instance that can be used to manage Kubernetes clusters and applications. To start using this shell, navigate to Kubernetes -> CLI. This shell is automatically installed with a Helm client and commands for Helm can be used immediately.